# Working of Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am currently reading "Zend Framework 1.8 
Web Application Development" written by "Keith Pope". In that he tells us to use 'ActionStack' so that the Controller for the category top-level menu will be called on every request. The source code for the the plugin is :

```
class SF_Plugin_Action extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract 
{
    protected $_stack;

    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) 
    {
      $stack = $this->getStack();

      // category menu
      $categoryRequest = new Zend_Controller_Request_Simple();
      $categoryRequest->setControllerName('category')
                      ->setActionName('index')
                      ->setParam(
                          'responseSegment', 
                          'categoryMain'
                      );

      // push requests into the stack
      $stack->pushStack($categoryRequest);
    }

    public function getStack()
    {
      if (null === $this->_stack) {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

        if (!$front->hasPlugin(
          'Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack'
        )) {
           $stack = new Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack();
           $front->registerPlugin($stack);
        } else {
           $stack = $front->getPlugin('ActionStack');
        }

        $this->_stack = $stack;
    }

    return $this->_stack;
  }
}
```

I have read the code for 'ActionStack' plugin. In the 'postDispatch' function it saves the current request and then in the 'forward' function it changes the current request's controller, action and also set parameters. Then what will happen to the current request ? How it will be executed ?

Also I heard [ActionStack is evil](http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/). As I am a newbie I didn't understand most of it, as he did not explained it(for newbies). Why ActionStack is evil ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the answer to my first question. As the action stack will be executed last (in the post dispatch) the current response object will be holding all content that got rendered for the request the user made, and the action stack will append the data to it. Hence the user will get content that he asked for + content that got rendered due to action stack

Answer (score 3):

ActionStack is evil as it promotes a bad practice: tying view-related logic to controllers. Additionally, it has a huge, negative impact on performance.

Typically, ActionStack is used to develop "widgetized" sites. You set up a list of widgets you need, and map them to individual controller actions, and then loop through the stack. The design flaw with this is that you're now executing N different controllers -- when, really, ONE controller is all you should use. Each individual controller should be able to map the incoming request to the necessary view and models. Instead, you're now basically executing an MVC triad simply to get back a bit of content.

The performance implications come from the fact that you now have to store the previous results in memory, and then re-dispatch -- which means running all pre/post dispatch plugins again, potentially having conflicts in state, and more.

The better approach is to have model-aware view helpers. You can use action helpers to marshal the appropriate models and inject the helpers, and then in your view scripts and/or layout, you simply invoke them. This honors an appropriate separation of concerns, and does not have the same performance implications.

(In ZF2, this marshaling is far easier, as you can define factories for individual helpers -- as such, you can simply *use* them in your view scripts, and not have to do anything special in the controllers at all in order to deliver widgetized content.)

Answer (score 0):

In your example. The front controller will start the execution of the current request and fire the routeStartup, routeShutdown and dispatchLoopStartup events. The dispatchLoopStartup event will call your plugin and your plugin will add a request object to the action stack.

Now the front controller will dispatch the current request, set the isDispatched flag of the current request to true and fire the postDispatch event. Now the Action stack plugin will get called. The front controller will pass the current request object to the Action Stack plugin as an argument and the Action stack plugin will update the controller, module, action properties of the current request object and set its isDispatched flag to false (Forward method).

Now the front controller will check the isDispatched flag of the current request object and since it was reset by the Action Stack plugin start the dispatch process again. And now your new request will get executed.

In short the front controller dispatches the current request, the action stack plugin resets the values of current request and the dispatch loop stars again.